# How to deploy Dockerized website on Heroku

Tags: docker, web, heroku, dockerfile

I have a simple static website with just a few lines of JavaScript. The website has been Dockerized with this Docker Compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  web:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/apache:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 443:8443
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I wanted to deploy this on Heroku, but I found out `docker-compose.yml` are not supported. So I translated everything in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/apache:latest
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443
```

Now, running `docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 <image-name>` gives me the same results as running the docker-compose so everything works.

I want to deploy this Container on Heroku, and I made an `heroku.yml`

```
build:
 docker:
   web: Dockerfile
 config:
   REQUIREMENTS_FILENAME: heroku.yml
release:
 image: web
```

I don't know if this config is enough to make it run correctly on Heroku. One of the doubts I have is the port forwarding. Indeed the build succeed in Heroku but the Deploy fails (actually it seems like it is stuck in a loop).

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

EDIT:

the errors I get are these:

```
apache 16:40:47.10 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
[Sun Jan 03 16:40:47.215603 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 38] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 03 16:40:47.246370 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 38] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 03 16:40:47.250502 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 38] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 03 16:40:47.257621 2021] [core:notice] [pid 38] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND'
```

And it feels like it is stuck in a Bootloop or something. I do get this "server certificate warning" also locally but everything seems to work fine so I guess that's not the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Dockerfile to something like this:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/apache:latest
COPY . /app
# Heroku container ports are dynamic. So change your Listen port from 8080 to ${PORT}
RUN sed -i "s/8080/\${PORT}/g" /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/00_status-vhost.conf
```

Heroku itself will handle https for you.